# SharePoint 2010 NTLM - Auth errors

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-2010, ntlm

The problem is as follows:
- I've got users defined on server A (domain controller),
- I've got SharePoint Farm installation on server B (fresh install)

After installation i have started the Profile Synchronization process, so i've got all the required users in sync. After i created a site i've assigned USER1 as its administrator / owner.

As i understand the USER1 user should have access to:
- site settings / permissions
- site content

Unfortunately i stuck with the situation where user can login on his my-domain\USER1 account, and he can access MOST of the pages. The rest:

- example.net/ (http://example.net/default.aspx IS accessible)
- example.net/test/ (http://example.net/test/SitePages/Home.aspx IS accessible)
- example.net/test/SitePages/

causes re-authentication.

It is really easy to solve by adding users / group defined in PDC to local WSS_WPG group, but i don;t think this is the solution.

I will really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in AD configuration.

Domain Users must have Bypass Traverse Checking enabled to avoid that issue.

For more information you can check following links:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787794%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739389%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- www.windowsitpro.com/article/performance/how-to-use-the-bypass-traverse-checking-user-right